Setting X and Y limit in matplotlib causes line errors in output
I'm trying to plot a circle and I want the background to look like a graphing paper, but when I try setting the X and Y limits the lines are messed up. The code for my circles is:
R1 = (n1 + n2 + n3) / 2

circle1 = (0, 0, R1)
circle2 = (0, R1, R1)
circle3 = (0, 2 * R1, 2 * R1)
circle4 = (0, 4 * R1, 2 * R1)

x2 = circle2[0] + circle2[2] * np.cos(theta)
y2 = circle2[1] + circle2[2] * np.sin(theta)
plt.plot(x2, y2, label='Circle 2')

x3 = circle3[0] + circle3[2] * np.cos(theta)
y3 = circle3[1] + circle3[2] * np.sin(theta)
plt.plot(x3, y3, label='Circle 3')

I set the X and Y limits to match what a graphing paper would have. Making the X and Y limits dynamic fixes the issue though. Below is the code for my X and Y limit:
plt.figure(figsize=(6.8, 8.6), dpi=100)
theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
ax = plt.gca()



# Set the limits for x and y axes
ax.set_xlim(-17.5, 17.5)
ax.set_ylim(0, 50)

but the result I get on the figure looks as such:


Your issue appears to be not successfully creating the grid everywhere, however you have not included the code which creates the grid which makes it difficult to assist. Having said that, there is a grid function in matplotlib which may simplify your life.

You may need to change values for n1/n2/n3 to get your circle, and change grid spacing, but here is an example where you use your custom graph limits to generate grid + ticks.
Basically, it generates ticks and lines with a 1 and 0.5 interval for your axis based on the min/max values you set.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n1 = 2
n2 = 3
n3 = 4

plt.figure(figsize=(6.8, 8.6), dpi=100)
theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)

R1 = (n1 + n2 + n3) / 2

circle1 = (0, 0, R1)
circle2 = (0, R1, R1)
circle3 = (0, 2 * R1, 2 * R1)
circle4 = (0, 4 * R1, 2 * R1)

x2 = circle2[0] + circle2[2] * np.cos(theta)
y2 = circle2[1] + circle2[2] * np.sin(theta)
plt.plot(x2, y2, label='Circle 2')

x3 = circle3[0] + circle3[2] * np.cos(theta)
y3 = circle3[1] + circle3[2] * np.sin(theta)
plt.plot(x3, y3, label='Circle 3')

# Set the limits for x and y axes + grid
ax = plt.gca()

x_min = -17
x_max = 17
ax.set_xlim(x_min, x_max)
ax.xaxis.set_inverted(True)
x_ticks = np.arange(x_min, x_max, 1)
little_x_ticks = np.arange(x_min, x_max, 0.5)
ax.set_xticks(x_ticks)
ax.set_xticks(little_x_ticks, minor=True)

y_min = 0
y_max = 50
ax.set_ylim(y_min, y_max)
ax.yaxis.set_inverted(True)
y_ticks = np.arange(y_min, y_max, 1)
little_y_ticks = np.arange(y_min, y_max, 0.5)
ax.set_yticks(y_ticks)
ax.set_yticks(little_y_ticks, minor=True)

plt.grid(which='both', axis='both')

Result is something like this :

